# Sierpinski triangles using turtle and recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I am trying to understand recursive functions, they look so complicated. The only thing I have understood so far is that their needs to be a base case and it is based on proof of Induction. How programmers think of simple base case is beyond by thinking up till now. Example fractals were solved in a book using only one line of base case. And here in Sierpinski triangles, I needed so many lines of code. Well, now I am close to it but still out of reach. Below is the code which works for order 0 and 1 but for higher orders, it adds more space. I know it isn't a pythonic code, but that's best I could write.

```
import math, turtle

window=turtle.Screen()
window.title('Sierpinski')
window.bgcolor('lightblue')

alex=turtle.Turtle()

def sierpinski(a,t,size):
    if a==0:
        for i in range(3):
            t.forward(size)
            t.left(120)
    else:
       sierpinski(a-1,t,size/3)
       t.forward(size/3)
       sierpinski(a-1,t,size/3)
       t.forward(size/3)
       t.left(120)
       t.forward(size/3)
       sierpinski(a-1,t,size/3)
       t.forward(size/3)
       t.left(120)
       t.forward(size*2/3)
       t.left(120)

sierpinski(3,alex,200)

window.mainloop()
```

Yes its a bit long, I am still not clear in my thought process

1. Can anyone explain what's wrong with my code?
2. How can it be made more pythonic?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found how to do it with the help of [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiGBNNDDgH0) which instructed me to divide it in half rather than one third.

so the code should have been

```
import math, turtle

window=turtle.Screen()
window.title('Sierpinski')
window.bgcolor('lightblue')

alex=turtle.Turtle()

def sierpinski(a,t,size):
    if a==0:
        for i in range(3):
            t.forward(size)
            t.left(120)

    else:
       sierpinski(a-1,t,size/2)
       t.forward(size/2)
       sierpinski(a-1,t,size/2)
       t.forward(size/2)
       t.left(120)
       t.forward(size/2)
       sierpinski(a-1,t,size/2)
       t.forward(size/2)
       t.left(120)
       t.forward(size)
       t.left(120)

sierpinski(3,alex,200)

window.mainloop()
```

## But can the code be more concise?

**Edit**

This would be enough:

```
def sierpinski(a, t, size):
    half = size / 2
    if a >= 0:
        sierpinski(a-1, t, half)
        t.forward(half)

        sierpinski(a-1, t, half)
        t.forward(half)
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(half)

        sierpinski(a-1, t, half)
        t.forward(half)
        t.left(120)
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(120)
```

That works because both `if` end `else` block were drawing triangles (the `else` block did it only to move the cursor, but still), but the `else` block made the recursive calls.

To make it *"more pythonic"*, you could put all of it into a class:

```
class SierpinskiTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
    def sierpinski(self, depth, size):
        half = size / 2
        if depth >= 0:
            self.sierpinski(depth-1, half)
            self.forward(half)

            self.sierpinski(depth-1, half)
            self.forward(half)
            self.left(120)
            self.forward(half)

            self.sierpinski(depth-1, half)
            self.forward(half)
            self.left(120)
            self.forward(size)
            self.left(120)

alex = SierpinskiTurtle()

alex.sierpinski(3, 200)
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Two lengths of the small triangle fit into one length of the bigger triangle. The code can be simpler if you completely remove the code from `if a == 0`, because it works without it as well ;) Otherwise, it looks fine to me.

Comment: That's very awesome, Thank you @zvone

Answer (score 1):

We can make the `sierpinski()` function simpler and faster using *stamping* instead of *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def sierpinski(depth, turtle, size):

    turtle.shapesize(size / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

    if depth < 1:
        return

    half = size / 2
    circumradius = half * 3 ** 0.5 / 3

    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(circumradius)  # to
        sierpinski(depth - 1, turtle, half)
        turtle.backward(circumradius)  # and fro
        turtle.left(120)

window = Screen()
window.mode('logo')  # make 0 degrees straight up
window.title('Sierpinski')
window.bgcolor('lightblue')

alex = Turtle('triangle')
alex.fillcolor(window.bgcolor())
alex.penup()

sierpinski(3, alex, 300)

alex.hideturtle()
window.mainloop()
```

This also has the advantage of drawing the triangle cented on the screen rather than off to one side.  The drawing can be optimized further by having the cursor move in a circular fashion around the triangle's inradius instead of moving to and fro about the center.

Comment: For a laugh, change `alex = Turtle('triangle')` to instead be `alex = Turtle('turtle')`   Then try some of the other possible shapes like `square`, `circle`, `arrow`, etc.

Comment: Lot of functions introduced that I wasn't aware of like window.mode(). Thank you so much @cdlane